# How to change config file in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a program that gets its language preference from the config file. I want to be able to translate the data in config file whenever a user selects preferred language from a control box in the user interface screen. what kind of function or method do ı need. I just need to change 1 word in the config file from for example English to French

Comment: Did you create your config file via Project Properties -> Settings? Because you should - and then VS will create a class for you to manage settings.

Comment: Are you building a .net desktop application? Or what is the context?
And what do you mean by putting the 'csv' tag?

Comment: this is a program done for automated machines it has several different languages in it , but to swtich between them we need to edit the config file  <setting name="Language" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Turkish</value> such to preffered language. i added my combobax all these languages with index but cant figure out what in order to do so that when ı choose from combo bax the config file changes itself. confif file is in VS but ı want the user to do it in the interface. it can reset itself or not ı dont mid the either way any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a .net desktop application that should work in multiple languages, you should check what is available out of the box for globalizing and localizing your application code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/

And specially the *Best practices for developing world-ready applications* section.